# How to add method names to log file in python

Tags: python, logging

How can I add method names to a log file in Python?

I want to record all the actions in the method along with the method name at the start of the message. Is it possible to automatically fetch the method name in log files using the logger?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html

Answer (score 2):

You can access certain parameters using strings from [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) of the `logging` module. Notably:

> `%(funcName)s`  Name of function containing the logging call.

The way you use this is by passing a string to the `format` parameter to `basicConfig`:

```
FORMAT = '%(funcName)s : %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```

Comment: Hi SuperBiasedMan,
thanks for the quick reply,it was working.